# .gitignore doesn't stop changes being tracked in files

Tags: git, command-line, github, terminal

Changes I make to a file that's within my `.gitignore` are being tracked by git.

File structure:

```
.gitignore
wp-config.php
```

Contents of `.gitignore`:

```
wp-config.php
```

When I change `wp-config.php`, and then run `git status` I see that it has been modified:

```
alex$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   wp-config.php
#
```

How to I stop tracking this file? I thought putting it in `.gitignore` would be enough.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

With `.gitignore`, only untracked files are ignored.

Once the file has been added, change to that file are not ignored.

In this case, you should use `assume-unchanged` or `skip-worktree` instead.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- wp-config.php
```

or

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- wp-config.php
```

Comment: what about the other files, do i need to add all  other files and folder like this? instead of adding git ignore?