# Do changes from git update-index propagate to other users?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm working with one other programmer using Github on an IntelliJ IDEA project. I'm not very experienced with Git and he's not very experienced with programming so we need a simple solution.

This question is not about myself updating the index--it's about whether my partner needs to do something, and if he doesn't will he commit changed .idea files?

I accidentally didn't include the `.idea` directory in `.gitignore` when first creating the repository. I've added it now and committed the new `.gitignore`, and I know that I need to do something else--use `git update-index --skip-worktree` to stop tracking those files (see [.gitignore doesn't stop changes being tracked in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513854/gitignore-doesnt-stop-changes-being-tracked-in-files)). My question is whether my partner will have to do something similar. I'm sure he will get the new `.gitignore` when he pulls this commit, but will he also have to run `git update-index --skip-worktree`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using gitignore to ignore (but not delete) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317169/using-gitignore-to-ignore-but-not-delete-files)

Answer (score 1):

To stop tracking the `.idea` directory, do the folowing:

Update the `.gitignore`:

```
echo ".idea/" >> .gitignore
```

Remove the `.idea/` directory from the index, leave the working tree files alone:

```
git rm --cached .idea/
```

Commit and push:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "do not track .idea folder"
git push
```

Now your team-mate will just need to pull this commit.

Comment: From my reading of other posts I believe this will cause git to remove his .idea files, which is not what I want.

Comment: @composerMike That's right, I don think there is way to do it without additional steps on the other repo. You team mate could get the folder back with `git checkout <hash before removing> -- .idea`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Both of You have to remove this file from index and add to .gitignore or You partner can checkout you solution with your job done.